Seemingly Do-able Gaussian
I've come across this integral. It looks totally do-able, but yeah I'm just stuck.
$$
I = \int_{\mathbb R^2} \exp \left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \right) \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)\right) dx~ dy
$$
Obviously this is simple if $a =b$, but I'm asking for the case where they're not equal.
Was wondering if people had any tips!

Edit:
So I've done a couple things, which will take too much time to write out in detail. I'll bullet point these here.
In polar coordinates this becomes
$$
I=\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{r} e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}\left(\frac{\cos^2\phi}{a^2}  + \frac{\sin^2(\phi)}{b^2}\right)}r ~ dr d \phi
$$

So in the case $a=b$, Mathematica can evaluate this directly.
$$
I= 2\pi a^2+\sqrt{2\pi^3} e^{\frac{a^2}{2}} a^3 \left[\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right]
$$
In the $a\neq b$ case, I did a couple tries:

I took the integral in polar coordinate form, and you can expand out the $e^{r^2 \sin^2(\phi) / 2b^2}$ in series form, and upon evaluating $\int d\phi$, you get an infinite sum of Bessel functions of the first kind. I was hoping to exploit the closure equation
$$
\int_0^\infty r J(x r) J (y r) dr = \frac{1}{x}\delta(x-y),$$ but the $r$ in exponent kills this dream...
I also expanded out $e^r$ in series form, and then the problem looks like
$$
I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int r^{n+1} \exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2} \left(\frac{\cos^2(\phi)}{a^2} + \frac{\sin^2(\phi)}{b^2}\right)\right)  dr d\phi.
$$ I then take $dr$ first, and resume it, but evaluating $\int d\phi$ doesn't go anywhere...




What have you tried?

So what do you think the solution is when $a=b$?  Or even $a=b=1$?  Please include in your post.

Solution: $$\frac{\left(4 a^2 b^2 \pi \right) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum {m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(1){\frac{m}{2}+2 n} \left(\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}}}\right)^m \left(\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{4 \left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}\right)^n\right)}{(1)_n (n! m!)}}{a^2+b^2}$$  The series can be expressed by: Srivastava - Daoust multivariable hypergeometric function.

@MariuszIwaniuk How does one even arrive here?

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\exp \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)\right)dydx=\\\int _0^{\infty }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }e^{\frac{1}{2} r \left(2-\frac{r \cos ^2(\theta )}{a^2}-\frac{r \sin ^2(\theta
   )}{b^2}\right)} rd\theta dr=\\\int_0^{\infty } 2 \exp \left(r+\left(-\frac{1}{4 a^2}-\frac{1}{4 b^2}\right) r^2\right) \pi  r I_0\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right) r^2\right) \, dr=\\\int_0^{\infty } 2 \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{r^m}{m!}\right) \exp
   \left(\left(-\frac{1}{4 a^2}-\frac{1}{4 b^2}\right) r^2\right) \pi  r I_0\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right) r^2\right) \, dr=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 r^m \exp \left(\left(-\frac{1}{4 a^2}-\frac{1}{4 b^2}\right) r^2\right) \pi  r
   I_0\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right) r^2\right)}{m!} \, dr=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{2+m} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)^{-1-\frac{m}{2}} \pi  \Gamma \left(1+\frac{m}{2}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{2+m}{4},\frac{4+m}{4};1;\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}\right)}{m!}=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{2+m} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)^{-1-\frac{m}{2}} \pi  \Gamma \left(1+\frac{m}{2}\right) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\left(\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}\right)^n \left(\frac{2+m}{4}\right)_n \left(\frac{4+m}{4}\right)_n}{n! (1)_n}}{m!}=\\\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{2+m-2 n} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)^{-1-\frac{m}{2}}
   \left(\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}\right)^n \pi  \Gamma \left(1+\frac{m}{2}+2 n\right)}{\Gamma (1+m) \Gamma (1+n)^2}=\color{blue}{\frac{\left(4 a^2 b^2 \pi \right) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(1)_{\frac{m}{2}+2 n}
   \left(\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}}}\right)^m \left(\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{4 \left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}\right)^n\right)}{(1)_n (n! m!)}}{a^2+b^2}}$$
The last double series can be expressed by: Srivastava - Daoust multivariable hypergeometric function see defintion (1.3) on paper.

Define
$$F(a,b)=\int_{\Bbb R^2}\exp\left(x^2+y^2\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)\right)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$
Everything is separable,
$$F(a,b)=\int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} \left[\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \exp\left(x^2+y^2\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)\right)\mathrm dx\right]\mathrm dy $$
$$F(a,b)=\int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}\left[\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}\exp(x^2)\exp(y^2)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2b^2}\right)\mathrm dx\right]\mathrm dy$$
$$F(a,b)=\int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}\exp(y^2)\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2b^2}\right)\left[\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}\exp(x^2)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}\right)\mathrm dx\right]\mathrm dy$$
So it's just
$$F(a,b)=f\left(\frac{1}{2a^2}\right)f\left(\frac{1}{2b^2}\right)$$
Where
$$f(z)=\int_{\Bbb R}\exp(t^2)\exp(-zt^2)\mathrm dt$$
Can you work this one out? Note it converges for $ z > 1$.

EDIT: I must have been sleepy when I was answering this question .... I missed the square root in the original post.

Op have: $e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ not $e^{x^2+y^2}$ ?

@MariuszIwaniuk Thanks for the correction. Feel free to downvote my post.
